# How to generate a x509 certificate using phpseclib 3?

Tags: x509, phpseclib

I'm really new to this certificates world. Is it possible to generate a x509 v2 certificate using phpseclib 3?

Comment: Why shouldn't that be possible? https://phpseclib.com/docs/x509#creating-certificates lists some examples - which one did you try? Which didn't work as expected? Also, how is this problem related to Composer?

Comment: phpseclib just does X509 v3 certs. What's the use case for creating a v2 cert? Maybe if you offer up some money the phpseclib authr would be willing to add v2 cert support